# create a div using javascript with its background colored randomly

Tags: javascript, html, css

1-Create an input for the person to type something and when pressing a button Create a Counter

2- A div with a colored background (randomly generate this color so that all counters are not the same)

3- The entire div must be clickable to increment the counter value

```
-- part 1 and 3 completed, part 2 incomplete

I would like to know if it is possible to create the divs with different colors, I implemented a random color code but it only changes the first div created and leaves the rest blank

as I couldn't post a part of the code on the site I'm leaving a link that shows the complete structure of the code
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8wz276rj/

Answer (score 0):

if you're only looking for code that generates random color then

```
const setBg = () => {
  const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
}
```

you can later set the div color through this.